# SQL Update if already exists, else insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have the following sql statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jos_vm_product_details (variant_id, global_variant_id, 
                  code, size, details, color, top, price) 
        VALUES ('$variant_id', '$global_variant_id', '$code', '$size', 
                '$details', '$color', '$top', '$price')";
```

This is just a basic INSERT sql. Is there a way for it to Update a record if the 'variant_id' is already present. If the 'variant_id' is not already there it should Insert a new one.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can try REPLACE INTO statement

Answer (score 4):

You can check [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jos_vm_product_details (variant_id, global_variant_id, 
                  code, size, details, color, top, price) 
        VALUES ('$variant_id', '$global_variant_id', '$code', '$size', 
                '$details', '$color', '$top', '$price')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
          global_variant_id = VALUES(global_variant_id),
          code = VALUES(code),
          size = VALUES(size),
          details = VALUES(details),
          color = VALUES(color),
          top = VALUES(top),
          price = VALUES(price)";
```

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY

```
INSERT INTO jos_vm_product_details (variant_id, global_variant_id, 
                  code, size, details, color, top, price) 
        VALUES ('$variant_id', '$global_variant_id', '$code', '$size', 
                '$details', '$color', '$top', '$price')";

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `code`=VALUES(`code`);
```

In T-SQL (2008 an higher) you could use MERGE